# Can I reclaim the broken line features in Design application drawings during prosecution?

Tags: design, obviousness, patent-drawings, prosecution, amendment

Received a Obviousness rejection on design application from USPTO. The prior arts are quite close to our design, **except a pattern on the bottom view**. However, the pattern on the bottom view is in broken line and no claimed originally.

Here is the question,
**can I rectify  the broken-line pattern to solid line and reclaim it in reply to the obviousness rejection**?

Answer (score 3):

MPEP 1504.04 discusses converting originally disclosed broken lines to solid lines:

> "an amendment that changes the scope of a design by either converting
>   originally-disclosed solid line structure to broken lines or
>   *converting originally-disclosed broken line structure to solid lines*
>   would not introduce new matter because such amendment would not
>   introduce subject matter that was not originally disclosed."

MPEP 1504.04(B) 6th paragraph. Emphasis added

Comment: If you could synthesize this to a yes or no, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many office actions on design patent applications that we have worked over years, In most cases examiner will not allow reclaiming a portion of the design by converting broken line to solid line.

Answer (score 0):

The MPEP provides an example where removal of three-dimensional surface treatment, such as beading, grooves, or ribs, would not be permitted, but that “an amendment that changes the scope of a design by either reducing certain portions of the drawing to broken lines or converting broken line structure to solid lines is not a change in configuration.” Thus, the examination policy changes appear to be in direct contradiction to the Patent Office’s previously published examination guidelines.

Comment: Could you cite the relevant sections?